# How to track keyup/keydown events in Javascript in iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, dom-events, mobile-browser

How to track keyup/keydown events in Javascript in iPhone browsers, basically I need to move the focus automatically to next form element once the end user has keyed-in maximum no of characters in a text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'tap' event in jquery mobile solved this.